# Identifier error in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I worte this following code to create my table, but every time I run it, it gives " invalid identifier " error.  Couldn't come up with a solution.

```
CREATE TABLE LIPS(
    PRODUCT_ID NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    PRODUCT_TYPE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    BRAND VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
    SHADE VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    SIZE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    PRICE NUMBER(10) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
CREATE TABLE "LIPS"(
    "PRODUCT_ID" NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "PRODUCT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    "PRODUCT_NAME" VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    "BRAND" VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
    "SHADE" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    "SIZE" VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    "PRICE" NUMBER(10) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: This matters because `SIZE` is a reserved word in Oracle, therefore you must quote fields that are named that.

Comment: Thanks @Donnie you beat me to the answer for  Codo's comment. :)

Comment: finally it worked! thanks... but can't i just give quotation mark only for **size** ?

Comment: Yes you can. Or better use another name like product_size, then you don't need quotes. With quotes you will have to use quotes in every query and always write the name in capital letters.

Comment: **appreciate the help**

Comment: @TanzidKhan if you want to follow best practice never have your column names the same as any reserved word such as DATE, SIZE.... etc

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is much better to change the name of the column rather than escaping the name:

```
CREATE TABLE LIPS (
    PRODUCT_ID NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    PRODUCT_TYPE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    BRAND VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
    SHADE VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    PRODUCT_SIZE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    PRICE NUMBER(10) NOT NULL
);
```